# Ajax request multiple retries in NodeJS for a time consuming request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am using ExpressJS framework and using jQuery to send an ajax request to server. This ajax request, sends request to an API on the server for a large number of items one by one, and takes sufficiently long time ( around 10 minutes for 100 items ).

The problem is that while the server is communicating with the API and has processed, say 30 items, the browser sends the same ajax request ( which is waiting for a response from server ) again. This results in multiple ajax request being handled on the server. What is the solution for this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please show your code if you want forlks to try and help you figure it out.

Comment: @Paul Code is quite big. Problem is very general. I send an ajax request. Server takes much time to complete the request. But instead of just waiting for the response, the browser sends the ajax request again after some time e.g. after 2 minutes. Now, server is handling 2 requests simulataneously.

Comment: Ok,good luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting `server.timeout` in `/bin/www` file. As I had mentioned, I am using Express framework of NodeJS and if I set `server.timeout` to a value, say 30 minutes, then the browser keeps waiting for the ajax response for 30 minutes and does not send a new request. Here's where I added the timeout value in my `www` file:

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port + ' in '+process.env.NODE_ENV+' mode.');
});
server.timeout = 30*60*1000; // for 30 minutes
```